# IE8/9 not rendering ajax call return

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8

There are plenty of ajax calls on the website I am working with, but for some reason IE8/9 seems to have an issue with this one.

It works fine in all other browswers, including IE10/11.

For IE8/9, I've checked with Firebug,  it does send the data to the remote php file, receives it back and even shows correctly the HTML in the Firebug console, but gives a blank at the destination tag.

I also tried to output just plain text, to no avail.

I checked around and found some other IE8/9 issues with Ajax call, but not this specific one.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hook").change(function(){
pass_id=(this.value);
var seltop = $(this).attr('id');
var selbot = "";
var lastchar = seltop.slice(-1);
var url = "url";
if ( seltop.substring(0,1)=="b"){
    selbot = "model" + lastchar;
    url = "select_model.php";
}
else {selbot = "version" + lastchar;
        url = "select_version.php" ; }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"html",       
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function () {
  $("#"+ selbot).html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
    data: {passval:pass_id, pass2:selbot},
   success: function(data){
     $("#"+ selbot).html(data);
   }
   });
 });
 });
```

Here is the output a the remote php file:

```
<select id = "<?php echo $model ; ?>" name="model_id" >
<option value="">Modèle</option>
<?php


            while ($r= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $out="<option value='".htmlentities($r['model_id'],   ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."'>".htmlentities($r['model'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."</option>";
                            echo $out;
                            }
?>
</select>
```

A typical output of the above looks like this:

```
<select id = "model9" name="model_id" >
<option value="">Modèle</option>
 <option value='96'>Cruze</option>
</select>
```

The destination tag looks like this:

```
<td class="trim">
<div class="comp_select">
<select class="hook" name="model_id" id="model9" > 
<option  value="">Modèles</option></select>
</div>
</td>
```

I believe that's all there is to know.

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You're not using CORS are you?

Comment: @ExplosionPills. I had to google it before answering, which means that I never heard of it. So, I am sure not using it.

Comment: Depends.  What is `url` in the ajax request?

Comment: @ExplosionPills. It is a variable. It can be either select_model.php or select_version.php, depending upon the originating tag. Please check the script from the beginning. It's just a way to use the same script for the 2 situations I have on that webpage.

Comment: _“A typical output of the above looks like this”_ – that makes no sense; the `select` element is not closed, and after it you close `body` and `html` – putting _that_ kind of HTML code _into_ another document at a specific point would be nonsense. Please update to show _correct_ code.

Comment: @CBroe, good catch! I had those tags sitting there for no reason. I cleaned it up and I am now running another test with IE8 just in case that's the issue. One never knows with IE.

Comment: @CBroe, that was not that. I run new tests after dropping the 'bad' tags and the issue is still there.